# PHP Random Array with Previous/Next

Tags: php, arrays, random

Hopefully this'll be pretty simple for someone to help with, but my PHP is very limited so here goes:

I have a random array set up to pull in a different video on each page refresh, and I've set up a 'Next' link which, if pressed, refreshes the array and outputs the 'next' video. Thing is, it's not the 'next' video in the array as it's being passed through the random function and just outputting whichever is finds. In most cases, since there's only four videos in the array, it's the same video.

Each time the page is visited it needs to be a random video, but if 'Next' is pressed, it needs to continue in the array in a loop.

Here's my code so far:

```
<div class="video-container">
            <?php
                $randomNumber = rand(0,4);
                $videoArray = array(
                    '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46808655?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                    '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46803192?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                    '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46811051?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                    '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46817110?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                    '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46822673?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                );
                echo $videoArray[$randomNumber];
                $current_index = array_search($randomNumber, $videoArray);
                $next = $current_index - +1;        
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($videoArray > 0): ?>
        <a href="<?= $videoArray[$next] ?>">Next</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be mostly appreciated :)

Comment: do you mind to accept one of the answers or tell us how you worked it out if no answer helped you?

Comment: None of these answers were right/helped. I appreciate the effort, but I went with something completely different in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a `$_GET` parameter

```
<a href="play_video.php?v=<?=$next ?>">Next</a>
```

and `randomNumber`:

```
<?php

     $videoArray = array(/*  */);

     if(isset($_GET['v']) && (int)$_GET['v'] < count($videoArray)){
         $randomNumber = (int)$_GET['v'];
     } else {
         $randomNumber = rand(0,4);
     }
     $current_index = $videoArray[$randomNumber];
     $next = $current_index+1;
     if($next >= count($videoArray)){ $next = 0; }
 ........
```

Comment: I think you want `v=<?= $next ?>` in your link.

Comment: Also, I'd adjust it so that when the counter hits the end, it wraps back to zero. Otherwise, you'll likely never see the first few videos. (I.e., start at a random spot, go to next video until end, then start at a random spot again. Odds are low that you'll ever see the first video.)

Comment: @AlexHowansky but it wraps back to zero :)

Comment: Oops yes, OK. Was expecting to see the wrap code up in the if() statement, didn't notice it at the bottom, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
<div class="video-container">
        <?php

            if (isset($_REQUEST["video"])) {
                $randomNumber = $_REQUEST["video"];
            } else {
                $randomNumber = rand(0,4);
            }

            $videoArray = array(
                '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46808655?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46803192?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46811051?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46817110?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
                '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/46822673?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>',
            );
            echo $videoArray[$randomNumber];
            $current_index = array_search($randomNumber, $videoArray);
            $next = $current_index - +1;        
    ?>
</div>
<?php if ($videoArray > 0): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>?video=<?= $videoArray[$next] ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If the script is called with a parameter called video, it'll choose that as the 'random' number.

There are a couple of other tweaks that could to with adding, such as making sure that the chosen video exists, as well as thinking about what to do if someone hits Next when they're on the final video.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should store only urls in your array.

Second, you should pass the id for the next video as url parameter in the Next link.

```
<div class="video-container">
    <?php
            // Array with video urls
    $videoArray = array(
        'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46808655?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff',
        'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46803192?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff',
        'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46811051?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff',
        'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46817110?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff',
        'http://player.vimeo.com/video/46822673?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;color=ffffff'
        );

            // Verify if "videoid" has been passed and it is valid
    if (isset($_GET["videoid"])
        && is_numeric($_GET["videoid"])
        && ($_GET["videoid"] >= 0)
        && ($_GET["videoid"] < count($videoArray))
    {
        // videoid is valid, use it
        $videoid = $_GET["videoid"];
    }
    else
    {
        // videoid is invalid or not set, generate random videoid
        $videoid = rand(0, count($videoArray) - 1);
    }
    ?>
    <iframe src="<?php print($videoArray[$videoid]); ?>" width="650" height="366" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>
    </iframe>
    <?php
    // calculate id for next video with overflow
    $nextid = $videoid + 1;
    if ($nextid >= count($videoArray))
        $nextid = 0;
    ?>
</div>
<a href="?videoid=<?php print($nextid); ?>">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before any output of your script, type:
`session_start();`
Then do

> ```
> if(!isset($_SESSION['curVid'])) { 
>   $_SESSION['curVid'] = 0;
>   $_SESSION['videos'] = $videoArray;
>   shuffle($_SESSION['videos']);
> }
> if(isset($_GET['next'])) { 
>   $current = intval($_GET['next']);
>   if($current > count($_SESSION['videos'])) { 
>     $current = 0;
>   }
>   $_SESSION['curVid'] = $current;
> }
> $current = $_SESSION['curVid'];
> $video = $_SESSION['videos'][$current];
> $next = $_SESSION['curVid']+1;
>
> echo "<a href=\"./?next={$next}\">Next video</a>";
> ```